# Display email as html when client support it otherwise display as plain/text

Tags: c#, .net

I want to display email as html if client dont support for html it shud show mail as text/plain. I have written code but not sure can anybody check it how to check for multicontent and multi mimetype here.

```
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);

foreach (string adress in to)
{
    mailMessage.To.Add(adress);
}

string path = string.Empty;

var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mailMessage.Body, null, "text/html");
```

Comment: If you build up the HTML email with tables it should work for everybody, if not, you could always reffer to the online version (link)

Answer (score 0):

```
    ContentType mimeType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html");

    // Add the alternate body to the message.               
    AlternateView alternate = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mailMessage.Body, mimeType);
    mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(alternate);
```

Comment: isnt it the same as i did here  var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mailMessage.Body, null, "text/html");

Comment: where are you binding htmlview ? could you please show the code?